# MYSQL - how to get zero value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table, here the structure

```
id    price      net_price

1     20000      19800
```

the type data price and net_price is double, when i run this query

```
SELECT CAST(net_price - price as unsigned) WHERE id = 1
```

the result is 18446744073709551416 , i want the result value is 0.

thanks before

Comment: Price is never double. It's why decimal was invented

Comment: ok thanks for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned value for -200 is 18446744073709551416.

Use below if you want to make negative value 0:

```
select case 
        when net_price - price < 0
            then 0
        else net_price - price
        end
from t
where id = 1;
```

Also, it's recommended to use Decimal type instead of double to do monetary calculations as double can't represent the values exactly.